# JDK16 ZGC problems when started

Tags: java, zgc

Recently，I try to do some test on JDK16's new GC ,namely ZGC ,but when I plan to reset the value  of GC paramter -XX:+UseLargePages and the JVM  start failed .In  the log ,it says ,

> [2021-04-15T20:11:10.094+0800] Heap Backing File:
> /hugepages/java_heap.13015 [2021-04-15T20:11:10.094+0800] Heap Backing
> Filesystem: hugetlbfs (0x958458f6) [2021-04-15T20:11:10.095+0800] Min
> Capacity: 28672M [2021-04-15T20:11:10.095+0800] Initial Capacity:
> 28672M [2021-04-15T20:11:10.095+0800] Max Capacity: 28672M
> [2021-04-15T20:11:10.095+0800] Medium Page Size: 32M
> [2021-04-15T20:11:10.095+0800] Pre-touch: Disabled
> [2021-04-15T20:11:10.095+0800] Available space on backing filesystem:
> N/A [2021-04-15T20:11:10.095+0800] Uncommit: Implicitly Disabled (-Xms
> equals -Xmx) [2021-04-15T20:11:10.095+0800] Failed to commit memory
> (Not enough space) [2021-04-15T20:11:10.095+0800] Failed to commit
> memory (Not enough space) [2021-04-15T20:11:10.095+0800] Failed to
> commit memory (Not enough space) [2021-04-15T20:11:10.095+0800] Forced
> to lower max Java heap size from 28672M(100%) to 28432M(99%)
> [2021-04-15T20:11:10.095+0800] Failed to allocate initial Java heap
> (28672M) [2021-04-15T20:11:10.102+0800] Runtime Workers: 10 parallel
> [2021-04-15T20:11:10.102+0800] Using The Z Garbage Collector Error:
> Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception
> has occurred. Program will exit.

do have you the same problem? what did you do to solve the tough issue ?

Comment: What startup parameters are you using?  Also, it's not clear from our question but was this previously working on an earlier jdk or is this the first time you're trying zgc?

Comment: other startup parameters are default parameters,except this .i have work out this problems :it is effected  by Linux OS parameters .unlucky ,  I had forgot the os  parameters

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, ZGC doesn't seem to be smart enough to successfully use large pages (also known as huge pages or 2MB pages) in many cases. The startup *randomly* fails so often with large pages support enabled that I've opted to take the performance hit and add `-XX:-UseLargePages` to disable the large pages support. Note that ZGC has large pages support *enabled by default* at least on 64 bit Linux hosts.

It would be great if JVM had similar feature to PostgreSQL where it *by default* tries to use huge pages support to automatically falls back to normal 4 KB page allocations if huge pages fails for any reason.

I'm running with a system with zero *reserved* huge pages but swap and huge page overcommit enabled which seems to be good enough for all the other software but JVM.